# Order by last 2 characters string

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

This is the result of my query, but it doesn't order correctly. I want to order by the last 2 characters. The result should be: `Fa0/10` below `Fa0/9`.

```
Fa0/1
Fa0/10
Fa0/11
Fa0/12
Fa0/2
Fa0/3
Fa0/4
Fa0/5
Fa0/6
Fa0/7
Fa0/8
Fa0/9
Gi0/1
Gi0/2
Null0
Vlan1
```

My query:

```
SELECT inft.port FROM interfaces AS intf ORDER BY RIGHT(intf.port + 0, 2)
```

Second: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fde72/5)

Comment: you must get the number part and order about string and number separately

Comment: Tell us what DBMS you use and What are the possibilities for the values that are not being sorted correctly.

Comment: sql server, mysql , oracle?

Comment: @FilipeSilva I'm using mysql workbench and a mysql server

Comment: Store the two parts separately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT port 
FROM interfaces 
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(port, '/', 1), CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(port, '/', -1) AS SIGNED)
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fde72/8)

**OUTPUT**

```
|   PORT |
|--------|
|  Fa0/1 |
|  Fa0/2 |
|  Fa0/3 |
|  Fa0/4 |
|  Fa0/5 |
|  Fa0/6 |
|  Fa0/7 |
|  Fa0/8 |
|  Fa0/9 |
| Fa0/10 |
| Fa0/11 |
| Fa0/12 |
|  Gi0/1 |
|  Gi0/2 |
|  Null0 |
|  Vlan1 |
```

Comment: @SaharshShah: It indeed solved my problem, but can you explain the logic implemented? Please?

Answer (score 7):

Why you need `+ 0` ?? Simply remove it and it will work.

```
SELECT port FROM interfaces ORDER BY RIGHT(port, 2)
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/01d40/7)

Output:

```
PORT
------------
Fa0/1
Gi0/1
Gi0/2
Fa0/2
Fa0/3
Fa0/4
Fa0/5
Fa0/6
Fa0/7
Fa0/8
Fa0/9
Fa0/10
Fa0/11
Fa0/12
Null0
Vlan1
```

Comment: I edited my fiddle. As you can see you with mysql it orders different. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The order is correct - lexicographically.

You need to convert them to a number.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

You need to do `+ 0` after extracting last two chars to convert it into number

```
SELECT inft.port FROM interfaces AS intf ORDER BY SUBSTRING(intf.port, LOCATE('/', intf.port)+1, LENGTH(intf.port)) + 0
```

Comment: This won't work because the slashes will get taken into the RIGHT string when the value is less than ten.

Comment: Yes, it won't work. As Bradley mentioned, you first need to substring based on `/` and then plus 0 to convert it into number.